# kubectl: describe vs get -o <format>

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

In kubectl, both `describe` and `get -o <format>` can be used to get the details of a resource, I'm wondering what's the difference between the two? why does `describe` even exist if `get` can do the same thing and more?

Comment: According to the documentation, the -o flags is only supposed to change the output format.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

- `kubectl get` shows tables by default. (You can view/visualize large no of objects easily)
- `kubectl describe` shows the detailed description. (Better for a single object)
- `kubectl describe` is more flattened, has lesser data and easier to read than the full object data given by `kubectl get -o yaml`

Help output for reference.

`kubectl describe -h`

```
Show details of a specific resource or group of resources

 Print a detailed description of the selected resources, including related resources such as events or controllers. You
may select a single object by name, all objects of that type, provide a name prefix, or label selector. For example:

  $ kubectl describe TYPE NAME_PREFIX

 will first check for an exact match on TYPE and NAME_PREFIX. If no such resource exists, it will output details for
every resource that has a name prefixed with NAME_PREFIX.

Use "kubectl api-resources" for a complete list of supported resources.
```

`kubectl get -h`

```
Display one or many resources

 Prints a table of the most important information about the specified resources. You can filter the list using a label
selector and the --selector flag. If the desired resource type is namespaced you will only see results in your current
namespace unless you pass --all-namespaces.

 Uninitialized objects are not shown unless --include-uninitialized is passed.

 By specifying the output as 'template' and providing a Go template as the value of the --template flag, you can filter
the attributes of the fetched resources.

Use "kubectl api-resources" for a complete list of supported resources.
```

Answer (score 14):

A simple explanation could be:

`kubectl describe ..` == Filterred `kubectl get .. -o <format>` + relevant events

---

For debugging purposes it can be useful to look at both `describe` and `get -o <format>` since each one has relevant information that is not shown in the other.

Note that events can also be shown by running `kubectl get events` (for default namespace), or `kubectl get event --all-namespaces` (for all namespaces).

---

Some digging:

Running `kubectl describe` with extended logging `--v=8` shows that it calls the `events` API (the third call) with `involvedObject.name%3Dsome-pod`.

```
$ kubectl --v=8 describe pod some-pod 2>&1 | grep GET
I1216 17:09:00.453529    6918 round_trippers.go:416] GET https://100.190.50.200/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/some-pod
I1216 17:09:01.098053    6918 round_trippers.go:416] GET https://100.190.50.200/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/some-pod
I1216 17:09:01.265924    6918 round_trippers.go:416] GET https://100.190.50.200/api/v1/namespaces/default/events?fieldSelector=involvedObject.name%3Dsome-pod%2CinvolvedObject.namespace%3Ddefault%2CinvolvedObject.uid%3Dbf664be1-1cde-11ea-bce6-42010af00267
```

`kubectl get pod some-pod -o yaml` only calls the `pods` API.

```
kubectl --v=8 get pod some-pod -o yaml 2>&1 | grep GET
I1216 17:13:21.084386   28256 round_trippers.go:416] GET https://100.190.50.200/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/some-pod
```

Comment: Is there any rule or docs about what gets omitted from `describe`? (Like, I was surprised when `deploy.spec.containers[].lifecycle.preStop` wasn't visible.)

Answer (score 6):

According to kubernetes documentation:

```
kubectl -n <NAMESPACE> get <NAME_OF_RESOURCE>
```

> Prints a table of the most important information about the specified
>   resources. You can filter the list using a label selector and the
>   --selector flag. If the desired resource type is namespaced you will only see results in your current namespace unless you pass
>   --all-namespaces.
>   Source: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#get

```
kubectl -n <NAMESPACE> describe <NAME_OF_RESOURCE>
```

> Print a detailed description of the selected resources, including
>   related resources such as events or controllers. You may select a
>   single object by name, all objects of that type, provide a name
>   prefix, or label selector.
>   Source: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#describe

kubectl describe is supposed to give you more information .Even if, I agree with you, some resources have quiete the same informations with kubectl get or kubectl describe.

Answer (score 0):

One important difference need to mention: `describe` accepts the prefix but `get` need the exactly name.

```
$ kubectl describe TYPE NAME_PREFIX
$ kubectl get TYPE NAME
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get the summary of a specific resource using:

- kubectl get < resource >   < name >

While you can get detailed information with:

- kubectl describe < resource > < name >

Comment: Please update this comment to explain better. The information given from kubectl get can be very detailed