# Safest and best way to retrieve the current configuration file in yaml for a single or bunch of resources in a kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-pod, amazon-eks

I applied a file xyz.yml sometime ago in EKS (Amazon elastic kubernetes service cluster) to deploy a statefulset pod from my  local machine. This file is versioned in GitHub. However, there were few manual applies made using kubectl for this file to the kubernetes cluster after that, so it looks like the source file i have right now in GitHub might be out of sync from the cluster.
Is there a safe and easy way to retrieve this file in yaml directly from the cluster using kubectl so that i can use that from now in my GitHub source code. I do not want to make changes in my GitHub source code and then apply them to the cluster as the file might be out of sync.
If somehow i could directly retrieve the file in YAML from the kubernetes cluster, that would really help solve the problem. I tried --dry-run or kubectl diff but don't seem to be helping.
I am new to kubernetes, hence do not want to experiment with commands directly on the cluster.
Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Ashley

Comment: Does this answer your question? [kubectl: describe vs get -o <format>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57740304/kubectl-describe-vs-get-o-format)

Comment: Unfortunately that gives a summary description of the pod (or any resource), but not the exact configuration file in yaml that was applied when deploying it.

Comment: `get -o yaml` should get you something very close

Answer (score 1):

You can try with edit:

```
kubectl -n <namespace name> edit [deployment, pod, svc] <name>
```

Comment: Thanks herbertgoto. 
so lets say my pod is xyz
i should use
kubectl -n my-namespace edit pod xyz
?
since i don't have to edit anything there can i just exit simply or will that cause any issues?

Comment: It works similar to vi. You just copy the content and exit (no changes will be introduced).

Comment: Looks like mine is a single file that may have created lot of resources in terms of a pod, service, etc. Is there a way i can use that file from source code to do a dry run or a dummy apply without any changes to see if i apply it what is gonna happen in the cluster?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current YAML of individual resources with:

```
kubectl get <resource> -o yaml
```

But you can't get all the resources that you created with this file at once because Kubernetes doesn't keep track of the manifest files in which the resource definitions were supplied.

So you would need to check which resources were created by your file and get them individually as above. Or if all the resources in this file have common labels, perhaps you could get them more easily by these labels.